# Windows Store Debug Build fails after "Associate with Store"

Tags: windows, cordova, debugging, store

I run a Cordova Windows 10 / UWP app, all builds run fine in configuration x86 release *and* debug mode. 
After associating the app with the store, I'm not able to build the app in debug mode anymore, the following errors are thrown in the log:

> Error     ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\tools\Gatekeeper.exe
>   @"C:\Users\USERNAME\dev\CordovaShell\platforms\windows\build\windows\bld\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"'
>   returned exit code 1007
>   [C:\Users\USERNAME\dev\CordovaShell\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]    CordovaShell    C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets   318 
>   Error     Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe:
>   Command failed with exit code 1   CordovaShell        1    Error      Error Could
>   not find file ''. 
>   [C:\Users\USERNAME\dev\CordovaShell\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]    CordovaShell    C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets   318

The CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj ist definitely at the correct location. Also, release mode still works fine after store association. Does anyone get the same error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to the Windows Store so there's likely an "official" way to avoid this issue properly.  Regardless, I solved this problem by creating an App Package using the Debug configuration.  After associating the app with the Store,

1. Go to Project -> Store -> Create App Packages...
2. In the Create App Packages dialog choose "No"
3. Click Next
4. In the Select and Configure Packages dialog, choose an architecture and its Debug configuration
5. Click Create
6. Build your Debug configuration

   I gleaned this approach after reading this article [Package your Cordova app so that you can publish it to a store](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#windows-10)